# Plotly: Multiple x-axes with shared y-axis

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'day': [1,2,3,4,5], 'date': pd.date_range("2020-01-01", periods=5, freq="D"), 'value': [43,45,52,55,63]})
```

[image: Dataframe]

In my plot I want the "value" column to be the only y-axis, but have both the "day" and "date" columns as X-axes.

My regular plot looks like this:

```
fig = px.line(df, x='day', y='value')
fig.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Plotly does not support the following:

```
fig = px.line(df, x=['day', 'date'], y='value')
```

How can I display both day and date as x-axes either below one another, or one at the top and one at the bottom of the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `plotly.graph_objects` and set the `xaxis` type to `multicategory`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'day': [1,2,3,4,5], 'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=5, freq='D'), 'value': [43,45,52,55,63]})

data = go.Scatter(
    x=[df['date'], df['day']],
    y=df['value'],
    mode='lines'
)

layout = dict(
    xaxis=dict(
        type='multicategory',
        tickfont=dict(
            size=7
        )
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        tickfont=dict(
            size=7
        )
    ),
    margin=dict(t=20, l=20, r=20, b=20),
    height=300,
    width=600
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.write_image('fig.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Is there a way to only display the "date" every 10 ticks, but the "day" for every tick? Kinda like (but `fig.update_xaxes2` does not work):
`fig.update_xaxes(dtick=1)`
`fig.update_xaxes2(dtick=2)`

Comment: Not that I know, probably better to ask another question about how to format the ticks of a multicategory axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text annotation feature [doc](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/)

```py
fig = px.line(df, x="day", y="value", text=df.date)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text|%d/%m/%Y}', textposition='bottom center')
fig.show()
```

This gives you:

[image]

---

If you want to have the date only every `delta` steps:

```py
delta = 3
fig = px.line(df, x="day", y="value", text=[str(df.date[i].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) if i % delta == 0 else "" for i in range(len(df))])
fig.update_traces(textposition='bottom center')
fig.show()
```

Gives you:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: A very nice and simple solution, although for my purpose I would prefer having the dates at the top or bottom of the graph.